# String to Link in Server Side Java Code

Tags: java, html, string

I am having a string,I want to convert to link,But I am not able to do the same,My code is given below:

```
Content.append("<a href=\""+System.getProperty("application.middleware.webapplication.host")).append(":")"/"/">);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above doesn't compile. If you didn't try to put everything on one line, you would understand why more easily

Start by creating a variable for `System.getProperty("...")`. Then put one instruction per line. Then don't mix `append()` and the `+` concatenation operator. The code becomes:

```
String host = System.getProperty("application.middleware.webapplication.host");
content.append("<a href=\"");
content.append(host);
content.append(":")"/"/">);
```

And the last instruction isn't valid. To become valid, and make it a link, you would need something like

```
String host = System.getProperty("application.middleware.webapplication.host");
content.append("<a href=\"");
content.append(host);
content.append("\">Click here</a>");
```

Respecting the Java naming conventions (variables start with a lowercase letter) is also crucial in making code readable and understandable.

Answer (score 3):

what about a simple solution like this ?

```
String host = System.getProperty("application.middleware.webapplication.host");
String url = "http://" + host;
String linkText = "please click here";
Content.append("<a href='"+ url + "'>" + linkText + "</a>" );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Content.append("<a href=\"")
       .append(System.getProperty("application.middleware.webapplication.host"))
       .append("\">My Link</a>");
```